# not able to edit authentication header based on path location in Apache virtualhost?

Tags: apache2

The application for which Apache is reverse proxy behaves like this:

1. It requires basic authentication header to login to it.
2. For the paths starting from `/api/*` requires just Bearer token.
3. If there is basic token in header, the application returns 401, unauthorized http response - it requires needs only Bearer token.

CAS authentication is configured for all the URLs except `/api/*` path and I am setting the base authentication token inside vhost config file - to login a user without presenting a login form again after he/she authenticates with CAS.

Apache config file `enterprise-search.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName https://search.test.xyz
        ServerAdmin john@xyz

    RemoteIPHeader X-Client-IP
    RemoteIPInternalProxy 10.10.10.2
    LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined-forwarded

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/enterprise-search-access.log combined-forwarded
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/enterprise-search-error.log

    LogLevel debug
    
        CASRootProxiedAs https://search.xyz
    
    <Location />
        # authn type
        AuthType CAS
        CASScope /
        AuthName "KFUPM"
        # authz
        # Grant all groups access to the root
        AuthGroupFile "/etc/apache2/http-authz/enterprise-search"
        Require group all-enterpirse-search
        # Pass REMOTE_USER header to application
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)$
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
        RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic xxxxxxxxxx"
    </Location>

    # authz: local_groups
        <Location /all-enterpirse-search>
        AuthGroupFile "/etc/apache2/http-authz/enterprise-search"
        Require group all-enterprise-search all-enterpirse-search
    </Location>
        
    <Location /api/>
        # authn type
        AuthType none
        Allow from all
        Satisfy any
        
        # authz
        Require valid-user
        # Pass REMOTE_USER header to application
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)$
        RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1,NS]
        RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{RU}e
        RequestHeader edit Authorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3002/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3002/
    
    
</VirtualHost>
```

The behavior of `RequestHeader edit Authorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""` is to replace Basic token header that is passed by the client and it works fine.

But what I actually want is to set Basic token in `<Location />` and remove it in `<Location /api/>`. Using `RequestHeader edit Authorization "Basic[^,]+, " ""` inside `<Location /api/>` is not removing the basic token and the application is returning the API call with 401 response.

I am new to Apache configs, may be my approach to achieve my goal is not correct. Please suggest if there is better way to do this.

Thanks.